# Postgres UPDATE for single entity causes high CPU usage

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm working on a Java application (Spring boot + Hibernate) that stores reference data on a table in an AWS Aurora Postgres 9.6 database. That table has some data fields, a surrogate primary key and and index on two fields.

```
CREATE TABLE sdm
(
   id                  bigint        NOT NULL,
   external_id         varchar(30)   NOT NULL,
   month               date          NOT NULL,
   field_1             varchar(30),
   field_2             varchar(3),
   field_3             varchar(20),
   field_4             varchar(40),
   field_5             varchar(40),
   field_6             varchar(40),
   field_7             varchar(40),
   field_8             text,
   last_update_id      bigint        DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
   field_9             varchar(4),
   postcode            varchar(4),
   field_10            numeric(10),
   updated_at          timestamp     NOT NULL
)
WITH (fillfactor=70);

ALTER TABLE sdm
   ADD CONSTRAINT sdm_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sdm_ex_id_mon_ix ON schema.sdm USING btree (external_id, month);
```

The application receives messages, interprets them and stores that reference data while linking that reference data to some other objects in the database.

The symptom I've found is when that process is running, it causes a huge impact on the database, mostly due to CPU wait. The AWS metrics show close to 100% CPU usage and the application throughput is appalling (10 messages every couple of minutes).

[Sample AWS console performance insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60F8X.png)

Also, looking at the APM monitoring in NewRelic I can see that the update statements issued by the application for that table can take minutes to complete.

I wouldn't consider that table to be too large (~ 10M rows) nor too complicated (it has only two indices and it's referenced by four other tables with FK constraints).

A sample update statement issue by the application would be

```
UPDATE sdm set (field_1 = $1, field_2 = $2) where id = $3 and last_update_id = $4
```

That gives an explain plan like this:

```
Update on sdm  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=206) (actual time=0.078..0.078 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=6
  ->  Index Scan using sdm_pk on sdm  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=206) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = 12345)
        Filter: (last_update_id = 1)
        Buffers: shared hit=4
Planning time: 0.086 ms
Execution time: 0.106 ms
```

I've tried several things in order to fix this performance bottleneck but I wasn't able to have any positive effect on that. Some of the changes where:

- Fix the application logic to minimise the need for updates
- Fix the application to issue update statements that don't touch the indexed fields
- Dropped the FK constraints on the related tables
- Made the table sparser (fill_factor = 70) and ran VACUMM FULL

I'd appreciate any assistance on what other things I could try to improve the performance of these UPDATE statements.

Comment: Show minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain, but beware: that will actually update the rows) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this once I realised that the problem was not on the DB layer.

The actual problem was with the application layer.

The Java code (either Hibernate or the Postgres driver) were sending the query with a `NUMERIC` value while the table has the `id` field defined as `BIGINT`. That caused the DB to use a cast for the statement and not use the index for the query.

Note that the Java model for that table has the `id` field defined as `BigInteger`.

To fix that, I updated that column to be `NUMERIC(27)` and from that point onwards, the queries generated by the application started using the index and the performance increased dramatically.

So, to summarise, in a situation like this one, pay attention to how your Java application is querying the DB. If the types are different, it may ignore any index on the relevant table columns. Haven't checked this for other data types, but I think that it is wise to check this anyway.

Comment: Thanks alot. The same happened using spring r2dbc postgres. for `bigint` column, when we used `BigInteger`, it did not use the index. Using `Long` solved this.